# Java replaceAll(...) being ignored

Tags: java, string

I am trying to use Java `replaceAll()`but Intellij tells me that the result is being ignored.

[image]

I am aware Strings are immutable but from what I can tell I am using it correctly. Is there a more proper was to utilize this String method?

For clearly I will post the code in the picture below and `sb`is a `StringBuilder`

```
 String insert = sb.toString();
                insert.replaceAll("(\\(['0-9,]*\\',)",TABLE_NAME+"_seq.nextval,");
                writer.write(insert);
```

Comment: *"I am aware Strings are immutable"* - Yet you write code that assumes it would be mutable. Maybe you should reread what immutable means to strings and the string-manipulation methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign to result of `replaceAll` to something:

`String something = str.replaceAll()`